# Sitecore navigate Links are not updating for Local datasources

Tags: sxa, link-database

We are using Sitecore 9.0 with SXA 1.8. The links are not updating in the Link database while adding any SXA components in the pages with local data-source items. But, the links are updating for the data-source items which are referenced in the Global Data folder.

Is this a expected behavior for local data-source items or any way we can make it work?

The referrer links are showing as None even though it has been referred in a page data-source.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, rebuilding the link database did not help.

Comment: Finally, We got to know, it's an issue till SXA 1.8 and it is fixed from SXA 1.8.1. The issue is solved in 1.8 after installed the Sitecore provided patch.